# Cross-browser fixed aspect ratio for a div with max-width

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, responsive-design

My goal is to show an image (or other content) in a div with fixed aspect ratio, which has a maximum width, but will scale down if necessary.

The following jsFiddle shows, what I have got so far. It does work fine for IE8. In Firefox and Chrome the inner div does not fully fill the outer div, there is a small gap at the bottom. Safari shows a wrong aspect ratio.

http://jsfiddle.net/ywyQQ/2/

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fixed Aspect Ratio</title>
<style>
.keepaspect
{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: auto;


    /* Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    behavior: url(http://localhost/PIE.php);
}
.inner
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: auto;
    display: block;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="keepaspect inner">
           <img src=http://i42.tinypic.com/21e18cx.jpg width='100%' height='100%'>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I set it up, so it is cross-browser-friendly and in a way, that it always fills the outer div?

It should also work with a jwplayer embedded, as you can see in this example, which is not yet working. But the markup for a jwplayer embedding is there for testing/demonstration purpose:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kn2Ju/1/

I am not sure, if this will require two different setups.

Here is a fully working example, but it is based on the img tag, which I can't use. The content is not necessarily an img. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gMUkE/2/

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fixed Aspect Ratio</title>
<style>
#container
{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: auto;
}
#container img
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;

            /* Box Shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    behavior: url(http://localhost/PIE.htc);
}
.content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /*optional in case the poster image has exact aspect ratio*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
      <div id=container>
          <img src=http://i42.tinypic.com/21e18cx.jpg>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In firefox, you're seeing the "textual" `display: inline` image, so you get the small gap on the bottom. Add `display: block` to the image and the gap goes away. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ywyQQ/3/

Comment: Get rid of `height: 100%`! It's quite meaningless if you want to keep aspect ratio, because it instructs Safari to set image's height to page's height.

Comment: Somehow I missed, that removing `height:100%` fixes the behavior for Safari (wrong test). So my latest fiddle here, actually works fine for FF, IE, Safari, Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/dfpGx at least for an image. Now I try to get it working with the jwplayer. Both tests are in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the img tag:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/ywyQQ/5/

Comment: What exactly does this change? It still seems wrong for Safari. Firefox and Chrome can be fixed with Jared Farrishs tip for display:block. Here is another jsFiddle where I included both problems and applied the suggested things so far http://jsfiddle.net/dfpGx/

Comment: thats odd it looks fine in my Safari 5.1.7

Answer (score 0):

For images, the following jsFiddle is a working solution (as suggested by @Jared Farrish and @biziclop):
http://jsfiddle.net/vEMEw/

The other solution for images is the one I already mentioned in the question:
http://jsfiddle.net/gMUkE/2/

The only solution I found so far, which is (also) working for an embedded jwplayer and is responsive, is to use iframes. How much "cross-browser" this solution really is, I do not know. I tested it succesfully with all these browsers: FF 17.0.1, IE 8.0, Safari 5.0.3, Chrome  23.0.1271.97.

**CrossBrowserJWPlayerResponsive.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/media/jwadvanced/player/6/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/k2/assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/k2/assets/js/k2.noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Fixed Aspect Ratio</title>
<style>


#videowrap {
    width: 700px;
    max-width: 70%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="videowrap">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div id="uniquePlayerID">
                <iframe src="iframetmpl.htm" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**iframetmpl.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>100% Height / Width</title>
     <script src="/media/jwadvanced/player/6/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>jwplayer.key="YOURJWPLAYERKEY"</script>
        <style type="text/css">
        html,body { height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
        #player {
            height:100%;
            width:100%; padding:0; margin:-3px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="player">
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                jwplayer('player').setup({
            'file': '/path/to/movie.mp4',
            'hd.file': '/path/to/hd/movie.mp4',
            'image': '/path/to/movieImage.jpg',
            'autostart': 'false',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'wmode': 'opaque',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'listbar': {
                'size': '180'
            },
            'logo': {
                'timeout': '1.5',
                'file': 'images/logo.png'
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```